# Tutorials for Asp.net core 1.0 and .net core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

How do I get started with Asp.net core 1.0 with .net core 1.0. Please suggest some tutorials. I want to develop and deploy on linux.

Comment: Try Google - you can even talk to it :)

Comment: I am not sure why this question is heavily downvoted. She/he wanted to know what is the aggregate opinion of experts on .NET Core tutorials, what google's suggestions will not show. That being said the question is not well-put for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you search anything on Google?
It will give you lots of material:

You can check on [msdn Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/01/19/asp-net-5-is-dead-introducing-asp-net-core-1-0-and-net-core-1-0/),[Link 2](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1251/using-diagnostics-aspnet-mvc-core),[Link 3](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/01/21/what-is-microsoft-net-core-1-0/).

If you are new to this then I would suggest to take a deep look into this and then you should be good to go.

Answer (score 5):

The link for pluralsight is very informative but if you do not have subscription then you can go for following links

1. [ASP.NET 5 is dead – Introducing ASP.NET Core 1.0 and .NET Core 1.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/01/19/asp-net-5-is-dead-introducing-asp-net-core-1-0-and-net-core-1-0/)
2. [ASP.NET 5 With Open Source - Part 1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/efa3cf/Asp-Net-5-with-open-source-part-1/)
3. [ASP.NET 5 With Visual Studio Code: Part 2](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/efa3cf/Asp-Net-5-with-visual-studio-code-part-2/)
4. [Creating ASP.NET 5 Web Application With Visual Studio Code](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/efa3cf/creating-Asp-Net-5-web-application-with-visual-studio-code253/)
5. [Resolving ASP.NET 5 DNVM Upgrade Issue And Changing DNX Version](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/efa3cf/resolving-Asp-Net-5-dnvm-upgrade-issue-and-changing-dnx-vers/)
6. [ASP.NET Core: File System, Background Compilation, and Editors](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/efa3cf/Asp-Net-co-file-system-and-background-compilation-and-edi/)
7. [Creating HTTP/2 Supported Website With ASP.NET Core and Hosting In Windows 10 (IIS 10.0.x)](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/efa3cf/creating-http2-supported-website-with-Asp-Net-core-hostin/)
8. [Diagnostics in ASP.NET MVC 6 (ASP.NET Core 1.0)](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1251/using-diagnostics-aspnet-mvc-core)
9. [What is Microsoft .NET Core 1.0](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/01/21/what-is-microsoft-net-core-1-0/)

Comment: A codeschool course came out too. The first one is free.

Answer (score 3):

Here I am giving you the Link for pluralsight Tutorial where you can get start with ASP.NET core 1.0 (ASP.NET 5 ).You need to have pluralsight Subscription to View the Course Video , Which you may get free of cost for 6 month through Visual Studio Dev Essential Program.(Search google/bing for Visual Studio Dev Essential)

1.[Building a Web App with ASP.NET 5, MVC 6, EF7 and AngularJS](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aspdotnet-5-ef7-bootstrap-angular-web-app/table-of-contents)

2.[Play by Play: ASP.NET Core 1.0 on any OS with John Papa and Shayne Boyer](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/play-by-play-asp-net-core-1-0-on-any-os-john-papa-shayne-boyer)